# OpenGL - Grouping methods for neighbour points

Tags: opengl, mfc

I am making a 3D view using OpenGL which displays a cloud of points.
In the current version I am displaying each point independently.
Each point is defined by its position {Xi, Yi, Zi} and by a RGBA color {Ci}.

The points are defining data and as such they have a maximum alpha value when the data is 0% (interpreted as noise).
On the contrary, they have a minimum alpha value when the data is 100%.

I am looking for an efficient way to be able to group those points so that they would appear as polygon depending on the data of neighbor points (meaning alpha value).
I have tried to display all points using cube polygon method (all the points being far from each other in a constant distance)

An example of the view that I am having now after few trials is below.

[image: Current view]

The points are not displayed efficiently since the display varies a lot showing back-face and front-face depending on the camera's angle (the camera and light are not being carefully handled currently).
Also we can see a "star" effect (the alpha calculation on the data needs a redesign ?).
Do you know a way to group those points that would make those points look like a polygon (cube) when data is closer to 100% (alpha value of 1.0) and at the same time showing only 'meaningful' data (one of the points being part of the polygon should be culled) ?
For performance purpose, the 'meaningless' data (between 0% and a user-set level are ignored).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you need to find the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of your points which means finding non-ambiguous and efficient representation of a set of points.

Once you do that you will need to triangulate your mesh, usually using delaunay triangulation. [QHull](http://www.qhull.org/) provides such functionality.

Regarding your transperancy; for correct viewing you need to sort your polygons/objects, this is particularly a tricky problem when it comes for [sorting polygons specifically](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/164596-Transparency-issues-polygon-sorting-headaches).

Comment: Thank you Concept3D for your quick reply. Please let me analyze and check your reply. But it looks really interesting.

Comment: @Toyo if you need more info let me know.

Comment: Concept3D, I marked your answer as correct. I followed your advices and found out that the initial way I was thinking about (rendering with transparency) was not correct and basically stupid regarding my skills. From your answer, I re-thought the process.From you advices, I implemented a method with first: removing all points that are useless based on their color. Then go around the points, group them by checking their distances with other points, compute the convex hull/triangulate by groups, and then render. It works well. Thank you again for your advice.

Comment: @Toyo thanks for letting me know. I hope everything went well.